# need help Custom View with multiple buttons in Android

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

**Till now i am done with custom view by extending ImageView class.**

[image]

**Now ,**

I have to create custom view for drawing and 2 buttons on screen.

I have to show buttons and custom view separate. Buttons should not over custom view.

**how to do it..?**

[image]

need your help........

*My sample code..*

```
package com.androiddom.customview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomView extends ImageView {

     private Paint paint = new Paint();
     private Path path = new Path();

     public CustomView(Context context) {
         super(context);

         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(15f);

     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.onDraw(canvas);       

         canvas.drawPath(path, paint);       
     }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY();

        // Checks for the event that occurs
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);             

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             XYZ etc...

            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }


        postInvalidate();
        return true;
    }     

public void clear() {
        //Path path = new Path();
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Currently I'm calling customview class by from main activity like following method:

```
MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CustomeView tv = (CustomeView) 
    setContentView(tv);

    }
}
```

Comment: i have to create drawing app , on touch finger lines will be drawn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try using XML layout as follows...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.androiddom.customview
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </com.androiddom.customview>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**

Suppose, above XML layout name `activity_main.xml`. Now, update `MainActivity.java` As follows...

```
MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize your CustomeView object in this way 
        // then do what you want to do with this object
        CustomeView tv = (CustomeView) findViewById(R.id.custom_view);

        Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        tv.clear();

    }

}
```

**Another Update:**

Create a new method for clearing the drawing view in your `CustomeView.java` class as follows...

```
// start new drawing
public void startNew() {
    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
}
```

Then call this method inside the `onClick()`...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 

    tv.startNew();

}
```

You can find more help about custom drawing from [DrawingView](https://github.com/janebabra/Android_am_Beispiel_Bonus-Projekte/blob/master/Canvas/app/src/main/java/com/example/drawingfun/DrawingView.java)

Comment: i tried that , but only custome view was displayed.
Can u tell me that from main activity how can call this custome view class  ? 
using XML for arrangement.

Comment: hey one more help plz ..,
i wan to clear view from  clicking on button.

I am adding CLEAR method to custome view :
while calling that method in onclick , nothing happened.
view wasn't clear  .